# Arduino 5 Servos

Tags: arduino, power-supply

I have connected 5 servos to my Arduino. I know I need and external power supply but am not sure how much. When a servo says 4.5-6v is that per servo? How many total volts do I need and what batteries would be the best choice?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need a 4.5V-6V (let's call it 5V) supply, which can supply enough current to supply the sum of *all* the currents your servos will require, which will be connected in parallel. If each servo requires 500mA, and you have 5, and they can all run at once, then you need a supply capable of \$500mA * 5 = 2.5A\$, plus enough to run whatever other devices you have in the circuit, plus maybe 20% margin for robustness.

Comment: what batteries would u recommend?

Comment: @BDGapps You'd have to say what your servos require. Or better yet, do some research and figure it out yourself. Between google and manufacturer datasheets, the information is easily available.

Comment: if u can please help it would be greatly appreciated. I am quite unfamiliar with this. This is the servo's specs: http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__662__HXT900_9g_1_6kg_12sec_Micro_Servo.html?gclid=CN2kjbiav7cCFYyY4Aod1HcAaA

Comment: @BDGapps I don't see any specifications on current or power requirements there, so you may have to guess or determine them experimentally. In any case, you should try to figure things out yourself, and then you should ask more good, focused questions where you need help. The stackexchange paradigm does not work well for discussions. For that, maybe try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what am I "guessing". I have little to no experience with electronics can u please guide me. Am I talking 5volts or 5volts*5motors???

Comment: @BDGapps I think in the answer I said "you need a 4.5V-6V (let's call it 5V) supply".

Comment: I don't understand what this means, supply capable of 500mA∗5=2.5A. Can I just use 4 AA batteries.

Comment: @BDGapps That sounds like a [new question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I asked "what batteries would be the best choice"

Comment: @BDGapps maybe someone else will come along and design more of your project for you. Or maybe, as I said before, you could try to have this discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).